# Литература о паттернах

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, java

Посоветуйте литературу о паттернах проектирования, предпочтительно на русском языке.

Comment: А если не на русском? http://www.dreamsongs.com/Files/PatternsOfSoftware.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Head First Design Patterns](http://www.amazon.com/First-Design-Patterns-Elisabeth-Freeman/dp/0596007124) хороша особенно для начинающих. Много простых жизненных аналогий. Примеры на Java.

Есть [русская локализация](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6108824/).

Comment: Ну и GoF, конечно, никто не отменял. Классику надо знать.

Answer (score 3):

Классика - [Приемы объектно-ориентированного проектирования. Паттерны проектирования](http://www.books.ru/books/priemy-obektno-orientirovannogo-proektirovaniya-patterny-proektirovaniya-8451/)

Answer (score 1):

Для начала [это](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/programming/136766/) вот почитайте, потом есть хорошая книга (шаблоны проектирования в Java) с джава примерами. Ну а в общем понимание паттернов приходит с опытом.